# how to create only one subscribe() of this code

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I've made this code that do its work, using RxJS:

```
from(dateQuery.first())
  .subscribe((result) => {
      query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', result.createdAt);

      const dateFormat = moment(result.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm:ss');
      from(query.find())
        .map(el => el.map((e) => {
          return {
            id: e.id,
            username: e.get('username')
          }
        }))
        .mergeMap((array) => Observable.of({
          names: array,
          lastUpdate: dateFormat
        }))
        .subscribe(
          (next) => res.send(serialize(next)),
          (error) => res.send(serialize(error)),
          () => console.log('completed'));
    },
    (error) => console.log(error)
  );
```

My question: is it possible to create only one subscription instead of this two? Because I need to use result of the first subscription also in the other mergeMap before and I don't know how to store it if I try to do only one subscription.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
from(dateQuery.first()).pipe(
  tap(() => query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', result.createdAt)),
  map(result => moment(result.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm:ss')),
  mergeMap(dateFormat => from(query.find()).pipe(
    map(el => el.map((e) => ({
      id: e.id,
      username: e.get('username')
    }))),
    mergeMap((array) => Observable.of({
      names: array,
      lastUpdate: dateFormat
    })),
    tap(() => res.send(serialize(next))),
    catchError(error => of('Find error'))
  ))
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first idea from what I understood.

I have exported the first subscription in an observable and I reuse it to construct the second observable (`find$`) where I do the second subscription.

I don't know what `query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', result.createdAt)` does, so I put it in a `.do()` operator as a side effect. If you need to execute this method before executing the remaining code, return an observable or a promise from it and use a mergeMap as well.

```
    const dataQueryFirst$ = dateQuery.first();
    const find$ = dataQueryFirst$
        .do((result) => query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', result.createdAt))
        .mergeMap(result => {
           const dateFormat = moment(result.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm:ss');
           return from(query.find())
               .map(el => el.map((e) => {
                   return {
                       id: e.id,
                       username: e.get('username')
                }}))
               .mergeMap((array) => Observable.of({
                   names: array,
                   lastUpdate: dateFormat
               }))
           });
    find$.subscribe(
        (next) => res.send(serialize(next)),
        (error) => res.send(serialize(error)),
        () => console.log('completed')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it with a "switchMap" .
    Plus i  would extract some logic in functions to make it more readable. And i prefere the new "pipe" way of rxjs since v5.5.

```
from(dateQuery.first()).pipe(
    // TAP because it seems to be a sideeffect. If this could stop your stream, "filter" would be appropriate
    tap(result =>query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', result.createdAt)),
    // MAP because we can discard "result" and only need the Moment-Object in the rest of the stream
    map(result => getMoment(result.createdAt),
    // switchMap to switch to the second stream, because it is only one command (in a long pipe) you don´t need a explicit return-command
    switchMap( createdAt => 
        from(query.find()).pipe(
            // MAP because we now want a UserObjects-Array in our stream
            map(el => createUserObjects(el)),
            // MAP because we want our NamesUpdateList. Depending on the usage you may not need "Observable.of()" here
            map(userObjects => createNamesUpdateList(userObjects, createdAt ))
        )
    )
).subscribe(
  (next) => res.send(serialize(next)),
  (error) => res.send(serialize(error)),
  () => console.log('completed')
)

getMoment(date){
    return moment(result.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm:ss')
}

createUserObjects(el){
    el.map((e) => {
        return {
            id: e.id,
            username: e.get('username')
        }
    }
}

createNamesUpdateList(array, dateFormat){
    return {
        names: array,
        lastUpdate: dateFormat
    }
}
```

warm regards